# Identificar DIV por id complexo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho várias DIVs carregadas dinâmicamente via PHP assim:

```
<div class="projeto" id="-9-3-21"></div>
<div class="projeto" id="-3-1-77"></div>
<div class="projeto" id="-5-33-1"></div>
<div class="projeto" id="-9-23-11"></div>
<div class="projeto" id="-1"></div>
```

Um arquivo JS recebe uma ação quando se clica em alguns botões, e a resposta é um número. O que preciso é:

Quando clica no número 33 (exemplo), o jquery da um fadeout nas divs que tiverem esse número, no caso seria essa id="-5-33-1"

É possível?

Comment: Seria `33` no campo `id` ? ou no texto da `div` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, use o seletor de * no Jquery, que vai selecionar tudo que contém tal valor.
Coloquei um exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg30nmp1/3/) pra você ver

No meu caso, criei um span e escondi a div que tem id com o texto dele.

```
<span id="texto">33</span>

//No clique do span, esconda aqueles com o id que você quer
$('#texto').on('click',function(){
    $('div[id*="' + $(this).text() + '"][class="projeto"]').fadeOut()
});
```

Comment: Oi, deu certo. Mas se eu tiver uma outra div em outra área do site com um id com o número 33 (exemplo id="bt33"), ele some também. Não da pra condicionar isso apenas a div que tenham a class tal?

Comment: Claro, dá sim, vou corrigir pra você aqui e no fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `Seletor Contais` do Jquery.

```
$( "div[id*='@SEUVALOR']" ).fadeOut();
```